# Combining only specified data into a single csv file

Tags: linux, csv, sed, cut

I am familiar with combing csv files using cat. I also am familiar with doing so while specifying rows.

What I need to know though is how to combine only specified columns that start a specified row in the csv files. The csv files I am using are kinda wild but they are all the same format. I have no control over their output and am forced to figure out how to combine a couple hundred files (hopefully not manually).

Example of the data:

```
| Column1      | Column3 | Column4      | Column5 | Column6      | Column7 | Column8 | Column9 | Column10     | Column11 |
|--------------|---------|--------------|---------|--------------|---------|---------|---------|--------------|----------|
| garbage data |         | garbage data | garbage |              |         |         | garbage |              |          |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         |              |         |         |         |              |          |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         |              |         |         |         |              |          |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         |              |         |         |         |              |          |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | garbage      | garbage |         |         |              |          |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 1  |         |         |         | good data 1  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 2  |         |         |         | good data 2  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 3  |         |         |         | good data 3  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 4  |         |         |         | good data 4  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 5  |         |         |         | good data 5  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 6  |         |         |         | good data 6  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 7  |         |         |         | good data 7  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 8  |         |         |         | good data 8  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 9  |         |         |         | good data 9  | garbage  |
| garbage data |         | garbage data |         | good data 10 |         |         |         | good data 10 | garbage  |
```

**EDIT**: The desired output would be row 6 where "good data" begins down (files are 1000 to 2000 rows each) from Columns 6 and 10.

**EDIT 2**: Desired Output

```
| Column10     | Column6      |
|--------------|--------------|
| good data 1  | good data 1  |
| good data 2  | good data 2  |
| good data 3  | good data 3  |
| good data 4  | good data 4  |
| good data 5  | good data 5  |
| good data 6  | good data 6  |
| good data 7  | good data 7  |
| good data 8  | good data 8  |
| good data 9  | good data 9  |
| good data 10 | good data 10 |
```

All feedback is most welcome.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I just left an answer in the question under 'EDIT'..thank you!

Comment: Does your data actually look like that - with `|` and `-`, or are there commas as separators really? You describe it as `csv`...

Comment: verbal description of desired output can be ambiguous. The preferred method is to show the exact output you require the sample input. Don't make us guess. CSV, do you want `col6,col10` or `col6    | col10   |` etc? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion: col6,col10..I will clarify above.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help debugging your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43644661/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` and `cut`:

```
sed '1,6d' file | cut -f6,10
```

- `sed '1,6d'` will remove all lines up to the sixth
- `cut -f6,10` will extract the needed columns (using tab as the delimiter)

To process all csv files in one go:

```
sed '1,6d' *.csv | cut -f6,10 > output.csv
```

Comment: This looked promising but results in this error..I assume its because of character encoding? cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence

Answer (score 3):

If they really are CSV files,

```
awk -F, 'FNR>5 {print $6,$10}' *.csv > BigBoy.csv
```